# How to clone only selected branches from git?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-bash

I have 16 branches in my project and I wanted to clone only 4 of then named Dev, UAT, Preprod, Prod, how do i do?

If I clone this will clones all the branches.

I know how to clone single branch.

Comment: Are you aware that you’ll still clone the history of these branches?

Comment: @evolutionxbox, I am not, but I dont have any history, Simply clone my  branches.

Comment: Remember _commits are the history_. Unless you’re on the first commit every branch will have history.

Answer (score 3):

`clone` is a convenience shortcut that addresses some common use cases.  It does not directly support your use case, though you can still use it to simplify the process if you want.

**What `clone` Does**

Clone initializes a repo, sets the default remote (`origin`), sets a refspec, fetches, and (unless you tell it otherwise) checks out the default branch.

**What `--single-branch` Does**

The single-branch option mostly just changes the refspec so that `fetch`, by default, will only copy the one branch.

This has trade-offs.  It means your repo will silently ignore things like new branches.  Those cons may be small for a given use case, but at the same time the pros of limiting what you fetch will also almost always be small.  (If they aren't, you might want to consider whether there are other solvable problems affecting your repo, such as large files in the history that should be managed by LFS.)

**How to Get Four Branches**

You can still use `clone` with `--single-branch` to get things started.  Then you just need to modify the  default refspec for the remote so that it will fetch all four branches.  You do this by setting `remote.origin.fetch` (assuming the remote is called `origin`); see the `git config` docs at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config and search for `remoate.<name>.fetch`

```
# having cloned with single branch Dev...
git config --add remtoe.origin.fetch UAT refs/remotes/origin/UAT
git config --add remtoe.origin.fetch Prepod refs/remotes/origin/Preprod
git config --add remtoe.origin.fetch Prod refs/remotes/origin/Prod
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to clone a single branch first and then fetch the rest.

```
git clone -b Dev --single-branch <url> -- foo
cd foo
git fetch origin UAT Preprod Prod
git checkout UAT
git checkout Preprod
git checkout Prod
```