# Remove Github deploy references from local .git folder

Tags: git

I'm currently working on a project that is mainly made of very small files, which means the current project's size is very small (< 1 MB) and the history should be pretty small as well.

But when checking the `.git` folder's size, I saw it was a whopping 17 MB!

So I investigated a bit with the following one-liner (taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42544963/4016380)):

```bash
git rev-list --objects --all |
  git cat-file --batch-check='%(objecttype) %(objectname) %(objectsize) %(rest)' |
  sed -n 's/^blob //p' |
  sort --numeric-sort --key=2 |
  cut -c 1-12,41- |
  $(command -v gnumfmt || echo numfmt) --field=2 --to=iec-i --suffix=B --padding=7 --round=nearest
```

Which shown that I had a set of large HTML, JS and JSON files taking up all the space. Which is weird, as I only have Markdown files here (it's a documentation repository).

So I took one of the reference's ID, run `git show <ID>` and it displayed a deploy entry from Github Pages!

The weird thing is that I don't have the `gh-pages` branch locally, only the `main` one which does not have any single HTML/JS/JSON file in it (I checked the whole history).

But I have some references of deployments with the changes on each HTML / JS / JSON file.

So my question is: why does that happen, and how can I get rid of all these useless informations that I don't want to have locally?

Thanks in advance for your help!

**EDIT:** To be clearer, I do **not** have the `gh-pages` locally. If I try to `git checkout` it I get an error telling me it doesn't exist. If I check out `origin/gh-pages` it works and creates a local branch but barely increases the `.git` size (less than 1 MB more) despite this branch containing a lot of data.

Comment: When you clone or fetch from a repository, you get a copy of **all** of its history, not just selected branches. To fetch only selected branches, see existing questions such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615488/clone-just-the-stable-and-one-other-branch-in-git and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49039959/git-clone-specific-list-of-branches and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58446026/git-clone-only-specific-branches-from-github and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57674585/how-to-clone-only-selected-branches-from-git

Comment: Indeed, this solves my question! I used that and I my `.git` folder went down from 17 MB to 4.5 MB! Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by @IMSoP's comment:

> When you clone or fetch from a repository, you get a copy of all of its history, not just selected branches. To fetch only selected branches, see existing questions such as [Clone just the stable and one other branch in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615488/clone-just-the-stable-and-one-other-branch-in-git) and [git clone specific list of branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49039959/git-clone-specific-list-of-branches) and [GIT: Clone only specific branches from GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58446026/git-clone-only-specific-branches-from-github) and [How to clone only selected branches from git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57674585/how-to-clone-only-selected-branches-from-git) –

Answer (score 0):

You could use sparse-checkout with the sparse-index option to shrink the your working folder and index locally.

E.g. in your repo do:

```
git sparse-checkout init --cone --sparse-index 
git sparse-checkout set <path1> <path2> <pathN>
git checkout main
```

Comment: I don't really get what you mean - what are those `<path1>` `<path2>` etc. supposed to be?

Comment: Its normally used for speeding up mono-repo performance. E.g. path could be the backend top folder. In your case it's just your root folder: './'. 
Totally overkill solution, but then again so is trying to optimize a 17MB index ;)